# Как создать базу данных в C# ASP.NET (VS 2022)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Я не понимаю, как создать БД в C# в VS 2022. Из того, что говорил препод я понял, что вроде нужно сделать миграцию и потом как-то создать БД. Искал в интернете что-то по созданию БД, но не увидел четких шагов и нигде не видел слов про миграции.

Насколько я понял нужно создавать миграцию такими командами в терминале:

1. add-migration InitialMigration -project PhotoAlbums.Infrastructure
2. update-database

Но после первой же команды вылезают ошибки:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вся структура проекта выполнена верно

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можете пожалуйста объяснить как создавать БД?

Заранее спасибо

Comment: Я обычно делаю через консоль windows: **сd путь к проекту .csproj** -> **dotnet ef migrations add init** -> **dotnet ef database update**

Comment: Add-Migration нужно вводить в Package Manager Console. [Migrations Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/?tabs=vs)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov спасибо, помогли! Можете написать ответ, я помечу, как решение. Всем спасибо за помощь